# How to import a keystore using BouncyCastle's TLS Api

Tags: java, bouncycastle, ssl

I have a question about using BouncyCastle's lightweight TLS API (Java version). On the BouncyCastle website, I noticed that it says with the latest release (1.46), the TLS api supports client-authentication.

However, I don't know how to import existing certificates for the TlsClient to use. How does one import a certificate or a keystore to use with BC's TLS api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [answered](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Importing-an-existing-certificate-into-TLSClient-td3763095.html) a similar question on the BC mailing list recently.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.